# openCV in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am getting an error [I get an error opencv_core242.dll is missing] when trying to compile a test program from http://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/.

I tried to add the specified information in something called a environment variable, however I do not know if I am doing it correctly. Can anyone clearly state step-by-step what I am supposed to do to add as the value? I put the paths to the directories that I need but it doesn't seem to resolve this error when I try to build the program.

Comment: it is weird that you're getting that error when compiling. are you sure it is not when you attempt to run the program?

Comment: If you give some more specifics on exactly what the error is and when it is occurring I can probably help you out.

Comment: carlosdc - yes sorry, I mean when I try to run the debug.          Danny - The error is a missing library. I have the library in the correct location the issue seems to be with including it in the environment variable. I thought I set it correctly but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Follow this [link]( http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html) there are step by step instructiosn for MVS and envrionment variables

Comment: Have you correctly configured the "PATH" environment variable as described here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windowssetpathandenviromentvariable ? In my case, I've set up a variable OPENCV_DIR with value "C:\Libraries\OpenCV\build\x86\vc10" and extended the PATH variable by adding ";%OPENCV_DIR%\bin" to the very end.

Comment: Niko -- Yes. I even replicated exactly what you have done (except that my OS is 64x).

Answer (score 1):

@Code Head has got one of the answer.

Or you can just copy all the dll's in `opencv/build/vc11/bin` into your program directory.

I know this is really an ugly solution but this surely works for a starter. At least I myself find it really useful when I first started using OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

1. RightClick your project in "Solution Explorer"
2. Click Properties
3. Navigate to "Configuration Properties -> Debugging"
4. In "Local Windows Debugger -> Environment" Write:

   - Path=$(Path);C:\path_to_opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin

     or (if compiling 64 bit):
   - Path=$(Path);C:\path_to_opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin